# Fails to auto-mount device & Error mounting system managed device(Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, fstab, automount, disk-utility

I used auto-mount option in Ubuntu 14.04 for mounting my all drives at startup.

[image]

All drives mounts automatically on startup except /dev/sda3. (Let me clarify that /dev/sda3 is **ext4 file-system** and labeled Ext4).

**It gives error on startup and ask S for skip and M for manual mounting**.I skipped and try to mount with disk (installed app from dash earlier disk-utility), it gives error:

[image]

***But If I mount with command: `sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/pandya/Ext4` at startup (By pressing M for manual mount) or after started up (from terminal), then it mounts properly.***

Gparted also mounts that drive on `/media/pandya/Ext4` Successfully.

I also checked `/etc/fstab` and entry for /dev/sda3, which is proper

```
/dev/sda3 /media/pandya/Ext4 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

**I used same auto-mount options for all drive. Then why only one is not auto-mounting?**

Comment: Is there any information in `dmesg`? As the error says, try `dmesg|tail`.

Comment: @Jos [   75.112360] EXT4-fs (sda3): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value

Comment: I found a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1011257) relevant to this issue. As a workaround, edit the fstab to show "comment=x-gvfs-show" instead of "x-gvfs-show".

Comment: It would be helpful for other users accepting a working answer. Cheers.

Comment: @Jos: What does `comment=x-gvfs-show` do? Or just `x-gvfs-show` for that matter? I had `x-gvfs-show` inserted automatically as an option in `/etc/fstab` when editing (or rather creating) the mount options of an ntfs partition using the application Disk in Linux Mint (probably also an Ubuntu application).

Answer (score 7):

As [@Jos](https://askubuntu.com/users/149708/jos) suggested, this is the bug [Bug #1012081: util-linux needs updating to 2.24.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-disk-utility/+bug/1011257) and can be fixed by adding `comment=` in front of `x-gvfs-show`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck **Show in user interface**.

It boots and mounts properly, but is not visible in the nautilus file explorer.

Comment: This actually worked. Amazing.