# bad mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value

Tags: boot

```
[14.529446] UDF-fs: bad mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
```

My boot stop on this row......so I'm able to boot Ubuntu only using "advanced option".

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/454225/11522